# Insert Excel Spreadsheet Into Word From Access Database

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have an Access database with Excel spreadsheets (files) linked to a field in each record.

In Word, I have setup a mail merge which picks up the data from each record and I want to insert the spreadsheet which is linked to each record.

Word picks up the link for the spreadsheet, but I'd like to display this in a table format.

Is this possible?

Comment: Create macros in MS Word.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Can you be a bit more specific, any tutorial? Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ff688774.aspx and may press in any MS Office software Alt+F11. Press F2 and view Office VBA object. But one problem I not like VBA)).

Comment: Show the Developer Tab on the Ribbon 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608625.aspx and may record macros at your action. Alt+F8 - run and edit macros.